# Sorting database columns according to time in Android?

Tags: android, database

I am making an application in which I set the URI of a captured image in database, which I have done like this:

```
db.openDataBase();
                 Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                 ContentValues initialvalue = new ContentValues();
                 initialvalue.put("CreatedDate",cal.getTimeInMillis());
                 initialvalue.put("ImageUrl", outputFileUri.toString());
                 long rowis = db.insertRecordsInDB("Note", null,initialvalue);
                 db.close();
```

I want to get image  from listview sorted by date. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql Ordered Query Example :

```
SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY LastName DESC

SELECT * FROM Persons ORDER BY LastName ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong: ORDERBY

Right: ORDER BY